# would you like to import preferences from previous sql developer installation

Tags: oracle

First Time I am installing sql developer in my new laptop and I am being ask would you like to import preferences from previous sql developer installation. What should I need to do now?

Please suggest.

Comment: I have selected Yes. Now I am creating new database connection but I am not sure what user name , password and SID I need to give.

Comment: I also found that no oracle service available in services.msc... please help

Comment: Someone using your OS account has ran a previous version of SQL Developer. The new version sees these settings and is asking if you want to use them vs starting over.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a prior sqldev on this machine , ignore this dialog and close it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer is a *tool* which enables you to access a database. Without a database, there's no much use of it.

Therefore, as you asked *which username, password and SID you should enter*, make sure that there's an available database you could connect to. If there's none, you can install it on your computer.

I'd suggest you to go with [Oracle 11g XE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) which is easy to install (requires several <kbd>NEXT</kbd> clicks) and use. The same (download) page contains **documentation**, just in case you need it.